# How to update Winforms picturebox on GUI from live HTML video feed?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, aforge

I keep getting a "Parameter is not valid" error or a memory leak (and the picture doesn't update) when I run my code. I am trying to get frames from a local IP camera using AForge.Net. The exact error code that I get is:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
Parameter is not valid."

In my code, *feed* is the name of the winforms picture box.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine(camaddress);
            stream.Source = camaddress;
            stream.Login = camUser;
            stream.Password = camPass;
            stream.Start();
            //PictureBox.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            CaptureCamera();
            isCameraRunning = true;
        }

        private void CaptureCamera() {
            try {
                camera = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CaptureCameraCallback));
                camera.Start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Debug.Write("Exception encountered trying to capture camera:\n" + e.ToString() + "\n");
            }
        }


        private void CaptureCameraCallback() {
            log.Information("Camera Opened", testID);
            guiLogWrite("Camera Opened");
            while (stream.IsRunning) {
                stream.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(VideoStream_NewFrame);

            }
        }

         private void VideoStream_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) {
            try {
                //Image FrameData = new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame);
                if (feed.Image != null) feed.Image.Dispose();
                Bitmap FrameData = AForge.Imaging.Image.Clone(eventArgs.Frame);
                SetPicture(FrameData);
                FrameData.Dispose();
            } catch { }
        }

        private void SetPicture(Image img) {
            if (this.InvokeRequired) {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { SetPicture(img); }));
            } else {
                this.feed.Image = img;
            }
```

This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow so please let me know if I have forgotten something. I've spent hours looking at other stackoverflow threads and Google trying to find a solution.

Comment: FrameData.Dispose looks fishy. You dispose the image while its being used.

Comment: You're accessing `feed` (a PictureBox), from a Thread other then the UI Thread: you cannot do that. You can: 1. Move `feed.Image?.Dispose();` (note the Elvis) to `SetPicture` and set the Bitmap after that. Remove `FrameData.Dispose();` 2. Always set the cloned Bitmap to the same Bitmap object that you add as a Field to the Form. Set this Bitmap as the Image of the PictureBox before hand, then in `SetPicture()` just `BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> this.feed.Invalidate()));`, to repaint the Control. You can also use a Graphics object to draw the new Frame to that Bitmap object.

Comment: Btw, Check the frame rate... (how many new Frames you get in a second, you may need to tune it). Also, not that `Invoke()` is synchronous.